# Including header and footer to a custom location

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to include a wordpress header into a php file which is located in folder e.g.: wp-content/uploads/custom.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of this documentation: [Integrating WordPress with your website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website)

In your case, you can create the file content.php and add this code, I just tried this on my website and it worked:

```
<?php 
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // Gets the root directory URL
  $path .= '/domain_dir'; // Appends your WordPress installation URL
  require( dirname($path) . '/wp-blog-header.php'); // Require this to execute get_header();

  get_header(); // Executes header.php
?>
```